# Aggregation issue in MDX

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have a dimension table `dim_employee` with columns `employee_id`, `employee_name`, `department`, `language`

Sample Data would be like this

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+----------+
| employee_id | employee_name | department  | language |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+----------+
|           1 | ABC           | PROGRAMMING | JAVA     |
|           2 | BCD           | PROGRAMMING | .NET     |
|           3 | CDE           | TESTING     | JAVA     |
|           4 | DEF           | TESTING     | .NET     |
|           5 | EFG           | DESIGNING   | PHP      |
|           6 | FGH           | PROGRAMING  | JAVA     |    
|           7 | GHI           | PROGRAMING  | JAVA     |    
+-------------+---------------+-------------+----------+
```

And my fact table is

```
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| Department  | Language | Employee Count |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| PROGRAMMING | JAVA     |              3 |
| PROGRAMMING | .NET     |              1 |
| TESTING     | JAVA     |              1 |
| TESTING     | .NET     |              1 |
| DESIGNING   | PHP      |              1 |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
```

Out of this, I want to have the following statistics departmentwise language wise employee count.

So I created a cube with Hierarchy with two levels department and language. Also a measure `Employee Count` with count aggregate function.

Now with the following MDX

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    Hierarchize({[Dim_Dept.Hier_Dept].Members})
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Employee Count]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

I expect the output

```
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| Department  | Language | Employee Count |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| PROGRAMMING |          |              4 |
|             | JAVA     |              3 |
|             | .NET     |              1 |
| TESTING     |          |              2 |
|             | JAVA     |              1 |
|             | .NET     |              1 |
| DESIGNING   |          |              1 |
|             | PHP      |              1 |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
```

However I am getting the output

```
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| Department  | Language | Employee Count |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
| PROGRAMMING | JAVA     |              4 |
|             | .NET     |              2 |
| TESTING     | JAVA     |              4 |
|             | .NET     |              2 |
| DESIGNING   | PHP      |              1 |
+-------------+----------+----------------+
```

What could be the reason? How to resolve this?

Comment: looks like department is not getting taking into consideration - is there a relationship between department and employee count?

Comment: in fact i have both department and language. is that what you are asking?

Comment: looking at your example it looks like it is adding Employee Count for Language ok - so for Java this is 4 (i.e. 3 + 1) but then when you add Department it is being ignored by the measure - so I think somewhere the relationship between Department and Employee Count is not functioning

Comment: right. i am not able to figure out what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: I just write mdx - I'm not involved with cube design. Is your dependency between Language and Employee Count? Can you change this dependency to the highest level in the hierarchy Department?

Comment: You mean to create another fact with `Department` and `Employee count`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102982/discussion-between-ravindra-gullapalli-and-whytheq).

Comment: you need to play around with the cube structure as I think some meta data relationship information is missing: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d86b856e-41f7-4c81-b7cf-2a534e7afbbe/this-relationship-cannot-be-defined-because-no-intermediate-measure-group-or-dimension-tables?forum=sqlanalysisservices. Is `Department` also a stand-alone dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Crossjoin should return the expected output:

```
SELECT
    {
        [Measures].[Employee Count]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        CROSSJOIN(
            [Dim_Dept].[Department].MEMBERS,
            [Dim_Dept].[Language].ALLMEMBERS
        )
    ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

Comment: Both department and language are two levels under same hierarchy. I think cross join won't be possible. If I take department and language as two different dimensions, I could do a cross join. But I want hierarchical picture. I updated the expected output table for clear view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your two levels do not have the correct attribute relationships set up.

Do both levels have respective attributed hierarchies?

Is a relationship set up between them, in a similar way to these levels?

[image]

Ref: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-analysis-services/avoid-common-sql-server-analysis-services-problems

Comment: Yes. The relationship is set properly between these two levels.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli ...and a seperate attribute hierarchy exists for both levels? Do the levels original in different dim tables?